# How do I work on 1 git repository from 2 computers

Tags: git, bitbucket

this might be a trivial question for some of you but I can't seem to figure out how, or even if, this works. I have a repository setup on bitbucket connected with desktop. I want to be able to be able to work on it on the go with my laptop.

I have been able to clone the repository no problem but how do I go about committing/pushing to the repository once I have made changes to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have two machine Desktop (D), Laptop(L)

Work on D device.

1. `git status` will show you some changes.
2. `git stage` will make them ready for modified files as accepted for adding the changes to file permanently or adding new files permanently
3. `git commit` will acknowledge your message for the changes like a proof/reason for change or adding files. This will go to your local git which is in a simple term like a sql table with ID and changes patch.
4. `git push` will update the git/bitbucket server/remote. This is nothing but all above procedure in remote destination. In a simple way transferring all above three steps data to remote.

Work on device L

Above 4steps applied. Some case 4th step

> 4. `git push` will not work on some cases if from your **D device** you have pushed a commit of file which is having newer changes, and you have changed something else in the **L device** before taking the D device changes to the same file. In those cases you have to do a

5. `git pull` which will update your **L device** by dragging the changes done by **D device**. Upon fixing changes i.e. resolving  conflicts i.e. manually repairing files you can proceed with 3rd and 4th step. If there is no problem in push, then for your own satisfaction to get recent updates on other files you can do time to time git pull on both **D device** and **L device** after pushing the changes from **L device** and **D device** respectively.

You might want to read about or understand the flow. Google git workflow cheatsheet.

Some more helpful commands will be
`git reset`, `git stash`, `git checkout`, `git diff`, `git clean`, `git mv`, `git rm`, `git merge`, `git fetch`

1st step `git status` can be done at any point of time which gives you suggestions for what to do next only in consoles or so called git bash shells.

Ref:

[image: Git Cheatsheet]

Answer (score 0):

You can perform local commits on your laptop while offline, then push/pull origin when you are connected to the internet. Any changes commited while offline to your local have a history you can traverse but are not available to others using the GIT as these changes are not pushed. You can do all this either through Git bash (command line) or a GUI such as SourceTree.